# SwiftChart has no member chart

Tags: swift, swiftcharts

I am using the SwiftCharts library found [here](https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts).

I have the following code:

```
class ChartTestViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var chartView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let xaxis = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"]
    let yaxis = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    let letdoublearray = yaxis.map { Double($0) }

    let tuples = zip(xaxis, letdoublearray).map { ($0, $1) }


    let chartConfig = BarsChartConfig(
        valsAxisConfig: ChartAxisConfig(from: 0, to: 8, by: 2)
    )

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: 300, height: 500)

    let chart = BarsChart(
        frame: frame,
        chartConfig: chartConfig,
        xTitle: "X axis",
        yTitle: "Y axis",
        bars: tuples,
        color: UIColor.red,
        barWidth: 20
    )

    self.chart = chart // error here
    self.chartView = chart.view
```

I am getting an error at the `self.chart = chart` line saying chart is not a member of the class. I already have `chart` defined so I am not sure where else I need to create another chart variable.

Comment: What is `self`? What class is this code in? You need to provide more context.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: The problem is with the `self.chart` part, not the ` = chart` part.

Comment: I know. The problem is I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Try adding a `chart` property to your view controller class.

Comment: The documentation has this added: `var chart: Chart?` but if i add that then it conflicts with the other `chart` variable declaration

Comment: Don't add a local variable, add a property to the class.

Comment: Yep that was it. Forgot about that. Thanks. Create an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: That's a good example why it's generally discouraged from using the same name for properties and local variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your view controller does not have a `chart` property. Simply add one.

```
class ChartTestViewController: UIViewController {
    var chart: BarsChart!

    @IBOutlet weak var chartView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // lots of code here

        self.chart = chart
    }
```